# Add array to associative array/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm new to Javascript and I would like to know how to make an associative array in JavaScript. I want to push my array in the main array to for an associative array. I know how to do it in PHP.

**PHP equivalent:**

```
$associativeArray = [
    [
        'name' => 'Bob',
        'age' => '18',
        'address' => '442 Grand Ave'
    ],
];
```

How can I do the same in Javascript?

Here is my code:

```
var mainArray = {};

var arr = [];
arr['name'] = 'Bob';
arr['age'] = '18';
arr['address'] = '442 Grand Ave';

arr.push(mainArr);

console.log(mainArr); // output: {}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP. The Array is a different structure.

Comment: Use [an object literal for the `arr` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), and switch your push around to `mainArr.push(arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you use `{...}` to define [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) (key-value pairs, roughly equivalent to associative arrays in PHP), and `[...]` to define [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). What you're looking for is:

```js
var arr = [];

var obj = {};
obj['name'] = 'Bob';
obj['age'] = '18';
obj['address'] = '442 Grand Ave';

arr.push(obj);

console.log(arr);
```

Or more succinctly:

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'Bob',
  age: '18',
  address: '442 Grand Ave',
}];

console.log(array); // output: {}
```

On a further note, JavaScript does allow mixing numeric indexes (e.g. `arr[0]`) and string keys (e.g. `obj['name']`) on a single object, but in practice, this is generally discouraged because it can be quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a lot different than PHP. The example you have shown with PHP would not work with JavaScript. I am not sure what exactly you would like to achieve but here's sort of an updated code to what you were trying to do.

```js
var mainArray = {};

var arr = [];
mainArray['name'] = 'Bob';
mainArray['age'] = '18';
mainArray['address'] = '442 Grand Ave';

arr.push(mainArray);

console.log(arr);
```